# List of three-tuples to a dictionary of list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I need the first item in the each tuple to be the key that returns a list of lists of the corresponding items. For example...

This is my input data:

```
my_problem = [(1,20,400), (1,30,450), (2,40,525), (2,50,600), (2,70,680),(3,80,700), (3,90,980)]
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
my_solution = {'1': [[20,400],[30,450]], '2': [[40,525],[50,600],[70,680]], '3': [[80,700], [90,980]]}
```

My actual list has thousands of these tuples of varying lengths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict`. These nice structures are essentially dictionaries that can be initialised with a *default* value when inserting a key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

solution = defaultdict(list) # create defaultdict with default value []
for item in my_problem:
    solution[item[0]].append(list(item[1:]))
```

and to convert back to a dictionary (although this is unncessary, as a `defaultdict` already has the behaviour of a regular dictionary) you can do

```
my_solution = dict(solution)
```

### A Slightly Neater Formulation in Python 3

(kudos to tobias_k for pointing this out)

In Python 3, you can replace the ugly `item[0]`, etc. calls to use the following:

```
solution = defaultdict(list)
for first, *rest in my_problem:
    solution[first].append(rest)
```

Comment: With Python 3, you can also do `for first, *rest in my_problem:`

Comment: @tobias_k Nice! Inline unpacking is neat!

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {}
for item in my_problem:
    data[item[0]] = data.get(item[0], []) + [item[1:]]
```

Make a new dictionary to hold the results; go through the input list, and add it to the dictionary - if there's already a list there for a given key, add to it, otherwise start an empty list and add to that.

Answer (score -1):

```
#! python3
my_problem = [(1,20,400), (1,30,450), (2,40,525), (2,50,600), (2,70,680),(3,80,700), (3,90,980)]

import collections
my_solution = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k,*v in my_problem:
    my_solution[k].append(v)

print(my_solution)
```